# Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: Unable to locate specified web identity token file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-fargate, amazon-eks

I am deploying my service using aws eks fargate deployment.yaml file and my service will connnect to dynamodb and while loading the id it throws the error. Even though I have web token file by following command.

```
kubectl exec -n first-namespace first-deployment-fhghgj567kkk-257xq env | grep AWS

AWS_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::263011912432:role/firstRole
AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=/var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token
```

But still it throws the following error.

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: 
[EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: 
Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) 
and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), 
SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), 
WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: Unable to locate specified web identity token file: 
/var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token, 
com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@7b58e085: profile file cannot be null, 
com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@39cb0014: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]
```

I ssh into container and checked the token appears there its still present.

Can anyone please help? Thanks

Comment: Is your container configured to use a non-root user?

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue, in my case I had to upgrade the java sdk and add a service account, I have not tried to call dynamo myself, but s3 and lambdas are working fine. Here are the steps I followed, this is the docs link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/enable-iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html

First, enable OIDC

```
eksctl utils associate-iam-oidc-provider --cluster cluster_name --approve
```

Then create and apply your service account, note the role must have access to any service you want to use (dynamo):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fargateserviceaccount
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:role/MY_ROLE_NAME
```

On your pods, define the service account and env variables:

```
spec:
  serviceAccountName: <ServiceAccountName> (kubectl get sa)
  containers:
    - name: java-api
      image: <AccountID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<Repo>:<tag>
      env:
        - name: AWS_REGION
          value: us-east-1
```

Finally use WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider in your code

```
// Create Credentials provider using ENV variables -> Service account is used to run  Fargate
WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider awsCredentialProvider = WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider.builder()
        .roleArn(System.getenv("AWS_ROLE_ARN"))
        .roleSessionName(System.getenv("AWS_ROLE_SESSION_NAME"))
        .webIdentityTokenFile(System.getenv("AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE"))
        .build();
// Build client using explicit credentials provider
AWSLambdaClientBuilder builder = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(REGION)
        .withCredentials(awsCredentialProvider);
client = builder.build();
```

Comment: What should be the AWS_ROLE_SESSION_NAME?  Could it be anything? I don't think webhook is creating that env variable.

Comment: I suppose is the value in `eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn:` It's set automatically in my case

Comment: .roleArn(System.getenv("AWS_ROLE_ARN")) is setting the eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn. My query was for .roleSessionName. Do we specifically set it or let SDK choose a name?

Comment: Do we need to set access id and secret key in the env variable in order to use WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider OR it internally generates the temporary credentials(access/secret/token) everytime? Also when token is refreshed then s3Client bean in this example will get re-instantiated? If not, then how the client is making connection with the new credentials once old token expires?

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue but observed a logger

```
WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(): To use web identity tokens, the 'sts' service module must be on the class path
```

Adding the dependency `software.amazon.awssdk:sts` solved my issue.
Hence please try by adding the `sts` dependency of the right aws sdk version if above mentioned logger is present.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when using Kubernetes and updating the SDK version fixed it.

The containers in your pods must use an AWS SDK version that supports assuming an IAM role via an OIDC web identity token file. AWS SDKs that are included in Linux distribution package managers may not be new enough to support this feature.

You can find the minimum SDK version supported [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts-minimum-sdk.html).